# How to Redirect https://example.com/ to https://www.example.com/

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file as shown below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This was added to redirect http to https so the entire site is now in https version.

Now I want to redirect from non-www to www. When I type example.com I should be redirected to https://www.example.com/

How do I do that with an `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 6):

Non-SSL redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

SSL redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by Non-SSL and SSL redirection.
In my case the apache server is sitting behind a load balancer and all requests sent from load balancer to server are HTTP on port 80

Answer (score 0):

How about this as https uses port 443

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the following lines in to your .htaccess file and replace `mydomain.com` with the domain that you want to redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For this to work you will have to remove the existing entries that you mention in your question from the .htaccess file

Comment: Nope...it doesn't work Mr. Lawrence Woodman...with the above code my site is redirecting to ....

> https://www.mysite.com/https://mysite.com/%22

This is what am also facing when i tried the above code myself..Its just redirecting to somewr else..... 

Any talented technical people out here? I think it needs some manipulation in my already existing code in htaccess file..

> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS}
> off RewriteRule (.*)
> https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: @jeni The problem you describe is probably caused by the double redirection.  If you just put the code I mentioned in my answer into your .htaccess file without your existing code it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I might have the solution:

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.[domain].com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Replace [domain] and the extension to your own domain. Tell me if this doesn't work.