# Rewrite rules for with www and without www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find the answer of my specific problem.

Currently all users redirect to `https://www.mydomain.com` if they type one of the following.

- `http://mydomain.com` (Replace http to https and add www here)
- `http://www.mydomain.com` (Replace http to https here)
- `https://mydomain.com` (Append www here)

I have this code in my .htaccess for above conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I can't figure out how do I stop redirection of any subdomain. e.g. users shouldn't be redirect to `https` if type on of the following:

- `abc.mydomain.com` (subdomain can be any name)
- `http://abc.mydomain.com`

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There are some related issues - not 100% - but useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151112/how-to-redirect-https-domain-com-to-https-www-domain-com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hey Anubhava, It didn't work. I am getting loop redirect error.

Comment: Anubhava, your code only work for www and no www. But it still doesn't stop redirection of subdomain. http://abc.mydomain.com still redirecting to https://abc.mydomain.com. I don't want my subdomain to redirect to SSL.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake, fixed it now. Try again

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

kj

Comment: It doesn't work for subdomain. when I type abc.mydomain.com. It redirect it to https://www.mydomain.com